# Cannot use BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF with std::string

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

I'm using Boost's (v 1.71) strong typedef to differentiate a `std::string` but I'm having a few problems.

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::string, StrongString);
```

First, I would like to use `StrongString` with `unordered_map`, but when I overload the hash:

```
std::unordered_map<StrongString, int, std::hash<StrongString>> umap;
```

I get the compiler error:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1126:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::hash<StrongString>::~hash()’
```

Second, previously I was using string concatenation and invoking `string::length()`:

```
std::string s;
s += "c";
s.length();
```

However, when I now do:

```
StrongString s;
s += "c";
s.length();
```

I get:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘StrongString’ and ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})

error: StrongString has no member named ‘length’
```

I can fix the compiler errors by using `s.t` to access the internal `t` member of Boost Strong Typedef, but this cannot be the correct way to use it.

Comment: [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) does not know how to hash a `StrongString` you need to write a specialisation of `std::hash` for `StrongString`.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for that. And should I be able to use `StrongString` just like `string`, calling `.length()` etc?

Comment: What is a "strong" typedef supposed to be to you? If everything that knows `std::string` should accept `StrongString`, then it really seems like you want a regular old typedef. You are not dealing in a new type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro is generating a class that wraps and instance of a **primitive type** and provides appropriate conversion operators in order to make the new type substitutable for the one that it wraps.

`std::string` is not a primitive type.

The possible impl:

```
struct StrongString {
  StrongString(const std::string& s) : wrapped_(s) {}
  operator std::string&() { return wrapped_; }

 private:
  std::string wrapped_;
};
```

As you can see, `StrongString` does not have member functions, thus `s.length()` and `+=` do not work, but this might work: `std::size(s)` and `s = std::string(s) + "c"`.

`std::hash` is not defined for `StrongString`.

Comment: I didn't realise it was only intended for primitives. Thought i was using it wrongly.